# Can Photoshop CS6 and Lightroom 4 marked as "Distribute in US only", be activated anywhere in the world?

Tags: adobe

Some retail version of these software are marked as distribute in certain regions only. Is the activation locked to that region as well?

Comment: I haven't personally tried it, but as far as I'm aware, activation is not region locked. It would be a very risky thing for them to do, as region detection is not completely reliable.

Comment: This isn't a guarantee but I have used "Distribute in US only" Adobe things here in Canada. I know we're the official attic for the US, but still…

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to Adobe customer support.

Comment: A Geoblock on activation would be nasty, since Geo-IP stuff has become full of false something-tives given how much ipv4 space is constantly traded around in tiny packages since it has gotten scarce :)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to know is to try. Some people have reported success, but Adobe policies and procedures may change in the future.